# How to find the number of words of length n with a specific rule.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm given the following problem:

Consider a language that uses only {1, 2, 3}. The only rule this language has is that a '3' cannot follow a '3'. How many words of length n exist in this language?

From what I gathered, I need to establish a recurrence to solve this problem. I'm not exactly sure how I should go about doing so, however. I tried splitting

$x_n$= $a_n$ + $b_n$

in which $x_n$ is the total number of words of length n that follows the rule and that $a_n$ is the number of words that DO start with '3' while $b_n$ is the number of words that DO NOT start with '3'. This seems to do no good though. Any tips is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having trouble defining the recurrence relation due to the number of variables involved, consider that a string can start in one of the four possible ways:
$$
1XXXX ...\\
2XXXX ...\\
31XXX ...\\
32XXX ...\\
$$
If the first digit is a $3$ then the second is not a $3$.  However, the digits following a $1$ or a $2$ can be any word in the language.
Two of these four cases have an undetermined word of length $n-1$, and the other two have an undetermined word of length $n-2$.  This yields the relation $x_n = 2x_{n-1} + 2x_{n-2}$.

Comment: Much thanks for the response and help! I definitely understand the problem better with your explanation. However, I'm still having trouble grasping why we would only need to pay attention to the first letters only. The rules state that a 3 cannot follow a 3. Wouldn't something like 

1233XX...

or

31233XX...

break the rule?

Comment: The point of the recurrence is that the XXXXXX portion is also constrained to be within the language, so such cases are ruled out.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if $b_n$ is the number of "good" words that start with a 3 then each of those words has a word of length $n-1$ that does not start with a 3 by removing the first 3 so $b_n=2 \times x_{n-1}$. Also in a similar fashion $a_n= 2 \times x_{n-1}$ .